# Complex Object manipulation (matrix and empty list)

Tags: r, matrix

I've an R-Object created with the R script from the following link.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32552/how-to-calculate-the-maximum-distance-within-a-polygon-in-x-direction-east-west

R Script

```
#
# Plotting functions.
#
points.polygon <- function(p, ...) {
  points(p$v, ...)
}
plot.polygon <- function(p, ...) {
  apply(p$e, 1, function(e) lines(matrix(e[c("x.min", "x.max", "y.min", "y.max")], ncol=2), ...))
}
expand <- function(bb, e=1) {
  a <- matrix(c(e, 0, 0, e), ncol=2)
  origin <- apply(bb, 2, mean)
  delta <-  origin %*% a - origin
  t(apply(bb %*% a, 1, function(x) x - delta))
}
#
# Convert polygon to a better data structure.
#
# A polygon class has three attributes:
#   v is an array of vertex coordinates "x" and "y" sorted by increasing y;
#   e is an array of edges from (x.min, y.min) to (x.max, y.max) with y.max >= y.min, sorted by y.min;
#   bb is its rectangular extent (x0,y0), (x1,y1).
#
as.polygon <- function(p) {
  #
  # p is a list of linestrings, each represented as a sequence of 2-vectors 
  # with coordinates in columns "x" and "y". 
  #
  f <- function(p) {
    g <- function(i) {
      v <- p[(i-1):i, ]
      v[order(v[, "y"]), ]
    }
    sapply(2:nrow(p), g)
  }
  vertices <- do.call(rbind, p)
  edges <- t(do.call(cbind, lapply(p, f)))
  colnames(edges) <- c("x.min", "x.max", "y.min", "y.max")
  #
  # Sort by y.min.
  #
  vertices <- vertices[order(vertices[, "y"]), ]
  vertices <- vertices[!duplicated(vertices), ]
  edges <- edges[order(edges[, "y.min"]), ]

  # Maintaining an extent is useful.
  bb <- apply(vertices <- vertices[, c("x","y")], 2, function(z) c(min(z), max(z)))

  # Package the output.
  l <- list(v=vertices, e=edges, bb=bb); class(l) <- "polygon"
  l
}
#
# Compute the maximal horizontal interior segments of a polygon.
#
fetch.x <- function(p) {
  #
  # Update moves the line from the previous level to a new, higher level, changing the
  # state to represent all edges originating or strictly passing through level `y`.
  #
  update <- function(y) {
    if (y > state$level) {
      state$level <<- y
      #
      # Remove edges below the new level from state$current.
      #
      current <- state$current
      current <- current[current[, "y.max"] > y, ]
      #
      # Adjoin edges at this level.
      #
      i <- state$i
      while (i <= nrow(p$e) && p$e[i, "y.min"] <= y) {
        current <- rbind(current, p$e[i, ])
        i <- i+1
      }
      state$i <<- i
      #
      # Sort the current edges by x-coordinate.
      #
      x.coord <- function(e, y) {
        if (e["y.max"] > e["y.min"]) {
          ((y - e["y.min"]) * e["x.max"] + (e["y.max"] - y) * e["x.min"]) / (e["y.max"] - e["y.min"])
        } else {
          min(e["x.min"], e["x.max"])
        }
      }
      if (length(current) > 0) {
        x.array <- apply(current, 1, function(e) x.coord(e, y))
        i.x <- order(x.array)
        current <- current[i.x, ]
        x.array <- x.array[i.x]     
        #
        # Scan and mark each interval as interior or exterior.
        #
        status <- FALSE
        interior <- numeric(length(x.array))
        for (i in 1:length(x.array)) {
          if (current[i, "y.max"] == y) {
            interior[i] <- TRUE
          } else {
            status <- !status
            interior[i] <- status
          }
        }
        #
        # Simplify the data structure by retaining the last value of `interior`
        # within each group of common values of `x.array`.
        #
        interior <- sapply(split(interior, x.array), function(i) rev(i)[1])
        x.array <- sapply(split(x.array, x.array), function(i) i[1])

        print(y)
        print(current)
        print(rbind(x.array, interior))


        markers <- c(1, diff(interior))
        intervals <- x.array[markers != 0]
        #
        # Break into a list structure.
        #
        if (length(intervals) > 1) {
          if (length(intervals) %% 2 == 1) 
            intervals <- intervals[-length(intervals)]
          blocks <- 1:length(intervals) - 1
          blocks <- blocks - (blocks %% 2)
          intervals <- split(intervals, blocks)  
        } else {
          intervals <- list()
        }
      } else {
        intervals <- list()
      }
      #
      # Update the state.
      #
      state$current <<- current
    }
    list(y=y, x=intervals)
  } # Update()

  process <- function(intervals, x, y) {
    # intervals is a list of 2-vectors. Each represents the endpoints of
    # an interior interval of a polygon.
    # x is an array of x-coordinates of vertices.
    #
    # Retains only the intervals containing at least one vertex.
    between <- function(i) {
      1 == max(mapply(function(a,b) a && b, i[1] <= x, x <= i[2]))
    }
    is.good <- lapply(intervals$x, between)
    list(y=y, x=intervals$x[unlist(is.good)])
    #intervals
  }
  #
  # Group the vertices by common y-coordinate.
  #
  vertices.x <- split(p$v[, "x"], p$v[, "y"])
  vertices.y <- lapply(split(p$v[, "y"], p$v[, "y"]), max)
  #
  # The "state" is a collection of segments and an index into edges.
  # It will updated during the vertical line sweep.
  #
  state <- list(level=-Inf, current=c(), i=1, x=c(), interior=c())
  #
  # Sweep vertically from bottom to top, processing the intersection
  # as we go.
  #
  mapply(function(x,y) process(update(y), x, y), vertices.x, vertices.y)
}

# --- modified lines ------
scale <- 10
x <- c(29,  -3,  -9, -33, -11,  -3,  30)
y <- c(13, -38, -37, -22,  32,  39,  13)
df = data.frame(x,y)
p.raw = list(cbind(x=df$x, y=df$y))
# --- modified lines ------

p <- as.polygon(p.raw)

results <- fetch.x(p)
#
# Find the longest.
#
dx <- matrix(unlist(results["x", ]), nrow=2)
length.max <- max(dx[2,] - dx[1,])
#
# Draw pictures.
#
segment.plot <- function(s, length.max, colors,  ...) {
  lapply(s$x, function(x) {
    col <- ifelse (diff(x) >= length.max, colors[1], colors[2])
    lines(x, rep(s$y,2), col=col, ...)
  })
}
gray <- "#f0f0f0"
grayer <- "#d0d0d0"
plot(expand(p$bb, 1.1), type="n", xlab="x", ylab="y", main="After the Scan")
sapply(1:length(p.raw), function(i) polygon(p.raw[[i]], col=c(gray, "White", grayer)[i]))
apply(results, 2, function(s) segment.plot(s, length.max, colors=c("Red", "#b8b8a8"), lwd=4))
plot(p, col="Black", lty=3)
points(p, pch=19, col=round(2 + 2*p$v[, "y"]/scale, 0))
points(p, cex=1.25)
```

"Results" object looks like ![R Studio screenshot]![1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIhsS.png)

I query the "results" object with the following functions:

```
> str(results)
List of 12
$ : num -38.1
$ : list()
$ : num -37.3
$ :List of 1
..$ 0: Named num [1:2] -9.71 -1.96
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "-9.71327624860538" "-1.96223017923762.current"
$ : num -22.3
$ :List of 1
..$ 0: Named num [1:2] -32.74 7.37
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "-32.7446064645847" "7.36705694439348.current"

..more

> dim(results)
[1] 2 6


> class(results)
[1] "matrix"
```

The following command retrieve a Matrix (2 x 4) of x values from the list elements, dropping the lists with 0 elements (second and last) and the first column containing the row.names.

```
> matrix(unlist(results["x", ]), nrow=2)
          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
[1,] -9.713276 -32.744606 -18.62469 -11.472847
[2,] -1.962230   7.367057  29.71905   6.391298
```

I'm looking to a way to append a new row to the  matrix containing the corrispondent y value from the "results" object.

Desired matrix

```
[,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
[1,] -9.713276 -32.744606 -18.62469 -11.472847
[2,] -1.962230   7.367057  29.71905   6.391298
[3,] -37.2621603110288   -22.3103099746149  13.5127523544645   31.6573863434048
```

In another way I need to drop from the "results" object the empty lists and convert it to a matrix.

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Well, why not extract the `y` data in a similar manner and then use `rbind` to  produce your combined matrix?   And a nit:  This is not a "complex" object.  The word "complex" specifically refers to data in the complex plane, i.e. `x + iy` .

Comment: Sorry for "Complex", I mean "Complicated" (list object as a matrix element).

Comment: @Carl With the following function `>matrix(unlist(results["y", ]), nrow=1)
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]
[1,] -38.09319 -37.26216 -22.31031 13.51275 31.65739 38.98276` I get an 6 element matrix. I need to drop the zero list element to get a 4 element matrix to be used with `rbind` I could use `matrix(unlist(results["y", ]), nrow=1)[2:5]` as I know the position of the zero element lists , but I want a more general function

Comment: But what do you get from `unlist(results["y",])` ?  If you can show us what your `y`-values are, it'll be easier to explain how to filter and merge them.

Comment: `-38.0931852725618 -37.2621603110288 -22.3103099746149  13.5127523544645  31.6573863434048  38.9827645066922 
        -38.09319         -37.26216         -22.31031          13.51275          31.65739          38.98276  `